# How can I get a Specific Item Out of a List<Map<String, Object>>

Tags: java

When I run this code:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> beforeDelete = query("select count(*) from wp_announcement where announcement_id =" + announcementId, null);

System.out.println("This is the count : " + beforeDelete.get(0));
```

I get this result:

```
This is the count : {C1=1}
```

How can I get just `1`, instead of `{C1=1}`?

Comment: How about  `beforeDelete.get(0).get("C1")`?

Comment: Are you sure you want to make a list of maps? Only one map would do the work.

Comment: @Pshemo - Do you want to put that down as an answer, so I can give you credit? In the meantime, I'll upvote you. Thanks.

Comment: @navlag Nah, I am not sure answer with only this code would help anyone (except you) and unfortunately I don't have time to post proper answer. But feel free to upvote and accept any answer which adds explanation to my example.

Comment: To expand on @Pshemo’s answer: Your selection is evidently returned as a `List` of rows, each of which `Map`s each column (in this case only `C1`) to an object representing its value in that row. Since your select is a singleton, `get(0)` is good to obtain the only row, but you need to obtain the column value as well, which is what `get("C1")` does. Perhaps you could explain if your `query` is a method of your own, and what it does — perhaps a `java.lang.sql.Statement.executeQuery`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that the structure of the returned map is going to be exactly as you show, you could get the value inside `C1` key like this:

```
int val = ((Integer)beforeDelete.get(0).get("C1")).intValue();
```

Add safety checks to ensure that the result has exactly one element, and that the initial element has a key of `"C1"` which maps to a `java.lang.Integer`.

This should be safe as long as the query is fixed. If the query comes from some source outside of your control, you will need to work out some other way to access the result.

**Note:** Assuming that the query makes it into some RDBMS, you should parameterize the query to avoid injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `{C1=1}` because `beforeDelete.get(0)` returns a `Map<String, Object>`.

> How can I get just 1, instead of {C1=1}?

Just like you retrieve an element form a map i.e. using its key

```
beforeDelete.get(0).get("C1");
```